# Summing up scipy rows and filling it in the diagonal

Tags: scipy

I have a sparse matrix of large dimension and I want to take sum of elements of each row, i, and fill diagonal with the results. How do I do this?

My numpy approach:

```
A = np.sum(A, axis=1)
D = np.diag(A)
```

How do I approach this with scipy?

Edit: I am using scipy.sparse and initializing A as a csr_matrix. I have read the docs but perhaps I am misread or missing something. With sparse.diags(D), I just got a column array, i.e it didn't give me a diagonal matrix when I tried to turn the sparse matrix into np.array.

Comment: Clarify, are you using `scipy.sparse?  `A` or D`?  What have you tried?  Have you read the docs?

Comment: Sorry.. I added some comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a sparse matrix:

```
In [149]: from scipy import sparse
In [150]: M = sparse.csr_matrix(np.arange(6).reshape(2,3))
In [151]: M
Out[151]: 
<2x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 5 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [152]: M.A
Out[152]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

Sum on an axis:

```
In [153]: M.sum(axis=0)
Out[153]: matrix([[3, 5, 7]])
```

Note this is a dense `np.matrix`.  Since `sum` increases density, `sparse` returns this rather than a sparse matrix.

Convert that matrix to 1d `ndarray`:

```
In [154]: M.sum(axis=0).A1
Out[154]: array([3, 5, 7])
```

Use `diags` to make a sparse matrix:

```
In [155]: M1=sparse.diags(M.sum(axis=0).A1)
In [156]: M1
Out[156]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements (1 diagonals) in DIAgonal format>
In [157]: M1.A
Out[157]: 
array([[3., 0., 0.],
       [0., 5., 0.],
       [0., 0., 7.]])
```

Read `sparse.diags` to see its required arguments.  `sparse.dia_matrix` can also be used (but also read its docs).

Math on the `Dia` format matrix is likely to produce a `csr` format matrix.

Other diagonal creation commands:

```
M1=sparse.diags(M.sum(axis=0),[0], shape=(3,3))
M1=sparse.dia_matrix((M.sum(axis=0), 0),shape=(3,3))
```

Comment: Aha! I think I was just trying to get diagonal matrix without converting it to ndarray. Is there a reason why that needs to be done?

Comment: Wouldn't that defeat the purpose of trying to use sparse in the first place? I mean it is not nxn matrix but still. In my case, I am guaranteed to have something in diagonal since D is a full rank matrix. So it is reasonable for me to turn the sparse row into 1 ndarray.

Comment: The sum produced a `matrix` not a sparse matrix. It's always denser.  The `diags` and `dia_matrix` format only work with dense arguments.  I used `A1` for convenience in specifying `diags` args.  It doesn't change density.  You'd have to use `coo` style inputs to make a matrix from a sparse diagonal.

Comment: Without `A1` I need to specify the offset list: `M1=sparse.diags(M.sum(axis=0),[0], shape=(3,3))`